# regular expression for this format 00-0000000

Tags: asp.net

```
<td><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="registry_no"
                        ErrorMessage="Invalid Format!"  ForeColor="#a90329" Font-Size="Small" ValidationExpression="/^\d+(-\d+)*$/"/></td>
```

regular expression for this format 00-0000000

i want to validate the user textbox input , the format should be like this one : 00-0000000, two digits followed by a dash , followed by 7 digits .

```
        thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the exact number of repetitions with braces, like so:

```
^\d{2}-\d{7}$
```